# Google Sheet hyperlink response code

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with about 300 hyperlinks in one column. I'd like to write a formula for an adjacent column the would return the hyperlink response code (200 or 403/404) for the link on the same (or referenced) row, rather than testing each link individually. How would this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would be possible:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlFromCell).getHTTPHeaders().getResponseCode();
```

but be aware that if the custom functions were put in each adjacent cell in column 2 then they would re-calculate on every change to the sheet.

This would quickly eat through [your quota for fetch calls](https://script.google.com/dashboard). Despite it being 20,000 calls a day this would occur after 66 updates to the sheet if this happens in a day.

Much better would be to have a single command to process an entire column on a button press or a menu command call - that's still 300 separate calls which may run into a 6 minute execution time limit as they will occur synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonathan,
I cloned your code snip in the following function "LinkTest()", although I found getHTTPHeaders was not offered by the type-ahead wizard, per "LinkTest2()".  I am a little confused however, as I would expect "response" to show the actual value of the response code in all cases, not just with a 200.  Whenever I would browse to a bad link, I'd get a 403, 404 or 410 for example. The function in those cases, however, only returned an "#ERROR".  A little further digging ([here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3478)) revealed the "muteHttpExceptions" property.  When set to "true", it yields the desired results.

```
function LinkTest(urlFromCell) {  // didn't work for me...
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlFromCell).getHTTPHeaders().getResponseCode();
  return response;
}
function LinkTest2(urlFromCell) {  // better
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlFromCell, {"muteHttpExceptions": true} ).getResponseCode()
  return response;
}
```

Return: